# UIView.beginAnimations error with context

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code and I don't understand error:

Cannot invoke 'beginAnimations' with and argument list of type '(nil, context:CGContext!)'

My simple code is here:

```
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: ctx) <-- Error on this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIView.beginAnimations("xyz", context: nil)
```

This may will help you.

Comment: Applogy for this but you will pass the argument context is a CGContext type but if you go through the method you can see the type of context is mention UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>. So, You can fill with nil. It will not raise error.

Comment: You should post that in answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

As your error says that:

> Cannot invoke 'beginAnimations' with and argument list of type '(nil,
>   context:CGContext!)'

You re passing wrong type parameter to the function.

As per Documentation on [Animating Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:):

**Declaration**

```
class func beginAnimations(_ animationID: String?, context context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

**Parameters**

- animationID

  > An application-supplied identifier for the animations.
- context

  > Custom data that you want to associate with this set of animations.
  >   information that is passed to the animation delegate messages—the
  >   selectors set using the [setAnimationWillStartSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationWillStartSelector:) and
  >   [setAnimationDidStopSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector:) methods.

Hope this will help you to solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no requirement to pass in the context, just pass nil.

Also, perhaps try UIView.animateWithDuration() instead. This is tidier and more convenient to use, and allows for a handy completion block to be executed.